# How to implement Extensible Enterprise Single sign-on in ios13

Tags: ios, swift, single-sign-on, ios13

We all know that Apple introduce Extensible Enterprise Single Sign-on Extension on iOS 13. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/301)
is the demo video presented by Apple.

There are two types of Extension,

1. Redirect and
2. Credential

I want to work with Redirect Extension.
The below code shown in demo video.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var authController : ASAuthorizationController?
let authProvider = ASAuthorizationSingleSignOnProvider(identityProvider: URL(string: "https://example.com")!)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
@IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {
    if self.authProvider.canPerformAuthorization {
        let request = self.authProvider.createRequest()
        request.requestedOperation = ASAuthorization.OpenIDOperation.operationLogin
        self.authController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        self.authController?.delegate = self
        self.authController?.presentationContextProvider = self
        self.authController?.performRequests()
    } else {
        print("failed to perform authorization")
    }
}
```

}

How can I get the identity provider URL.
So my question is that how to implement Redirect Extension in my app and how to add identity provider url.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi @Samiul, have you implemented this?

Comment: I want to implement same thing, but not able to get much more information on this topic.

Comment: No @Ashish I can't do that yet.

Comment: Okay @Samiul, if you get any solution, then please ping me.

Comment: @Ashish We can work together to find out a solution if you want.

Comment: Hey Hi @Samiul, did you get solution for SSO. Yes, we can work together to find out solution for this.